# Resful APi ouput is changing from JSON to XML when we send BAD Request status as output

Tags: java, rest, soapui, postman, restful-architecture

I made a restful API which produces JSON format output (@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)). This is working as expected when the status is Created or Ok. But whenever I send output bad request with some error message in JSON format. I'm not receiving the expected JSON result with error message instead of that I'm receiving something like "Unexpected 'B'" when i use postman for testing. If I use soapui for testing it is giving result in Xml.

These are the annotations I have used for my method

```
@POST 
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("sample")
```

These are responses im sending based on request

```
return Response
            .status(Status.BAD_REQUEST)
            .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", " POST")
            .entity(JsonResponse)
            .build();

return Response
            .status(Status.UNAUTHORIZED)
            .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", " POST")
            .entity(JsonResponse)
            .build();

 return Response
        .status(Status.CREATED)
        .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST")
        .entity(JsonResponse)
        .build();
```

I have problem only when the return type is Other than Status created.

This is my object mapper class

```
private static final ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();
static 
{
  MAPPER.setSerializationInclusion(Include.ALWAYS);
  MAPPER.disable(MapperFeature.USE_GETTERS_AS_SETTERS);
  MAPPER.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true); //in response
  MAPPER.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);//in   request


}
public ObjectMapperProvider()
{
System.out.println("Instantiate ObjectMapperProvider");
}

@Override
public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> arg0) 
{
return MAPPER;
}
```

[I have used following response type in postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eNPt.png)

[This is the result I got for above request. Im expecting a json format output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwRdT.png)

[This result im seeing in soapUi in XML format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMv3K.png)

[This result im seeing in SoapUi in json format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFViS.png)

This is the response Im seeing when I sent 401 status code with error message in XML Format but im sending in JSON format.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
    <title>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials. 
    </title>
    <style type="text/css">
        <!--
     body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica,                            
     sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
      fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
      h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
      h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
      h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
      #header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font- 
      family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
      background-color:#555555;}
      #content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
      .content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin- 
       top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
       -->

        </style>
       </head>
         <body>
           <div id="header">
             <h1>Server Error</h1>
           </div>
           <div id="content">
              <div class="content-container">
                 <fieldset>
                    <h2>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid 
                credentials.</h2>
                     <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>
                 </fieldset>
             </div>
          </div>
          </body>
        </html>
```

If you need any other information let me know.

Comment: This is not XML but rather HTML probably produced but the web server container. How are you deploying the app exactly and what tech stack are you using to handle the RESTful communication?

Comment: I am using jersey Jackson and apache tomcat 8.5 for deployment.

Comment: OK it seems then that you're not returning a proper response or that the servlet container is not configured correctly. I suggest to check on how to handle such exceptions and translate them to responses.

Comment: If you have three different configurations for SoapUI for the three cases, check that all three are configured the same way?  This looks to me like the web server that is receiving your REST call is refusing to forward the request to your REST handler, because you don't have the right credentials to go in...

Comment: It is working fine when i deployed it in my local when i deploy it in server then i’m seeing the issue. But everything is same code and same configuration in my local and the server